# SQLServer2008 CopyDatabaseWizard Job Fails - Unable to determine if owner of job has server access

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2008, ssis, user-permissions

Trying to copy a SQL2000 database on server TUNA to destination server MOJITO which runs default instance of SQL2008 (at ServicePack1) via the CD Wizard. Resulting job fails on MOJITO with this in application log:

**SQL Server Scheduled Job 'CopyDatabaseWizard_TUNA_MOJITO_1' (0x64AB69F2880A7E4DA3708546C33DFF40) - Status: Failed - Invoked on: 2010-09-23 17:05:04 - Message: The job failed.  Unable to determine if the owner (CBMIWEB\johna) of job CopyDatabaseWizard_TUNA_MOJITO_1 has server access (reason: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'CBMIWEB\johna', error code 0x5. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15404)).**

There is a credential on MOJITO defined for CBMIWEB\johna. There is a proxy on MOJITO that uses that credential. The job has one step and in the properties I have set the RUN AS value for the job to be the name of the Proxy. The proxy is established for SSIS jobs.

The "owner" of the job is also CBMIWEB\johna which is a domain userid in the local Administrators group of each machine (both TUNA and MOJITO). This userid has been granted the permission to **Logon as a Batch Job** on both servers.

TUNA is a Windows 2000 standalone server; MOJITO is Windows 2003. I can logon to each server as CBMIWEB\johna.

I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 4):

Help came from another forum:
[MSDN forum with correct answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/10b2137c-a7ba-4974-b4fb-5474330fe815)

"The SQL Server uses the SID's of the User, not the name. On the other Server the same User has another SID.

I suggest to change the Job Owner to "sa". That should work. Later you can change the Job Owner back to CBMIWEB\johna."

Comment: Thanks for coming back to post the correct answer to this. You just helped me out :).